# Develop algorithm for determining data availability

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, data-warehouse, change-data-capture

We are using a Change Data Capture tool to migrate source data to a target database in near real-time.
The challenge is to identify as accurately as possible the data migration latency that exists between 
source and target. The latency reporting capabilities of the tool are not to our satisfaction and so I
have been tasked with developing a process that will better monitor this specific metric.

There are two main reasons why we need to know this:

1: Provide our users with an accurate data availability matrix to support report scheduling. For example,
   How much time should pass after midnight before scheduling a daily reconciliation report for the 
   previous day given that we want this information as soon as possible?

2: Identify situations when the data mirroring process is running slower than usual (or has even stopped).
   This will trigger an email to our support team to investigate.

I am looking for some general ideas of how to best go about this seemingly simple task

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming related topic. It might better fit on Programmers SE.

Comment: Hmm, Other than the [java] tag it seems perfectly on-topic for me.

Comment: What is the tool that u are using for CDC and near real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred approach is a dedicated heartbeat or health-check table.
At the source the table has an identity column (SQLserver) column or value from a sequence (Oracle) as main identifier; a fixed task name string; fixed server string (if no already identified by the taskname; and the current time.

Have a script/job on the source to insert a record every minute (or 2 minutes  or 10 minutes)

In the CDC engine (if there is one), add a column with the time the change event was processed.

At the target, add a final column defaulting to the current time at insert.

A single target table can accommodate multiple sources/tasks.

The regular blibs will allow one to see at a glance whether changes are coming true, whether the application is generating changes or not.

A straightforward report can show the current latency, as was as the latency over time.
It is nice to be able to compare 'this Monday' with 'last Monday' to see if things a similar, better or worse.

Cheers, Hein.

Comment: Adding a dedicated table is ok for a high level check but we need finer monitoring since latency differences across different tables exist. One approach I have been working with is to get the max updatetime on each table for both source and target every hour or so and compute the differences. This works well for active tables but not so well for tables that do not change often as the differences may appear quite large.

Comment: The reason for the big difference in updatetime between source and target is because the target simply doesn't see the last transaction which is ok. The problem is the transaction that occurred prior to that was a long time ago, hence the big gap in difference

Comment: "latency differences across different tables exist" Really? Does the CDC method not attempt some more or less transactional ordering? Then you have even bigger challenges than the fine granularity for some (active), coarse for other (low use) tables. The helper table also has the advantage of getting all data on one system, not having to connect to source as well as target. Good luck.

Comment: We have opened several problem tickets with vendor already. Some due to the tool's inability to report errors when the replication process is not working and also due to duplication. The point here is I am trying to introduce a monitoring process outside of the tool for the reasons mentioned before. I will, however reconsider the dedicated table approach also